# Cannot set the screen brightness via PCI

Tags: 16.04, brightness, backlight, pci

I was trying to use `xbacklight` to set my monitor brightness under the 
`i3-wm`. But nothing was happening after typing:

```
xbacklight -dec 10
```

To investigate I tried to set the brightness via the PCI bus directly:

```
lspci 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller:...
setpci -s 00:02.0 0xF4.B=80
pcilib: sysfs_write: write failed: Operation not permitted
```

It appears that I don't have the right to right through this PCI Bus even in `root` mode.

I am under **Ubuntu 16.04**. And the unity screen brightness tool was working under **Unity** environment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I installed a new software named **Brightness Controller** through which I'm able to control my brightness.
To Install use the following commands

- Open terminal via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Run command to add the PPA:

  ```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller
  ```
- Then update the respository and install the utility:

  ```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install brightness-controller
  ```

Done!!
Now remember one thing! You may have to adjust it again the next time you open your computer(means it is not permanent!)

Now if you want to **remove** the utility, simply run command:

```
sudo apt-get remove brightness-controller && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to write directly in the file (the `PATH` can be a bit different depending on your computer's screen):

```
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/brightness
```

If you can't write in it, you can modify the right with the `chmod` command

```
sudo chmod 660 /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/brightness
echo "2000" > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/brightness
```